# file_get_contents() erro!

Tags: php, html5

Possuo o formulário html:

```
<div id="formulario">
        <form method="POST" action="Controller/jsonTeste.php">
            CEP: <input type="text" name="cep" placeholder="Insira o cep" required/>
            <input type="submit" /></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

E o arquivo php:

```
<?php
$formCEP = $_POST['cep'];
$formCEP = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $formCEP);
$url = file_get_contents('http://viacep.com.br/ws/$formCEP/json/');
?>
```

Ao passar a variável $formCEP para a ULR: http://viacep.com.br/ws/$formCEP/json/, recebo um "Warning" como reposta, mas ao digitar um CEP valido para a URL, é aceito como válido. Como resolver?

Comment: Qual warning você recebe?

Comment: Acho que o problema é somente o uso da variavel $formCEP
Concatena ela na URL

$url = file_get_contents('http://viacep.com.br/ws/' . $formCEP . '/json/');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está substituindo o `$formCEP` na sua String. Quando usa strings de aspas únicas, a interpolação não funciona. Para resolver, utilize aspas duplas.

```php
<?php

$formCEP = "15047200";
$formCEP = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $formCEP);

echo 'http://v...content-available-to-author-only...m.br/ws/$formCEP/json/';
echo "\n";
echo "http://v...content-available-to-author-only...m.br/ws/$formCEP/json/";
```

---

Portanto, para funcionar, altere

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://viacep.com.br/ws/$formCEP/json/');
```

para

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://viacep.com.br/ws/$formCEP/json/");
```

Código funcionando: https://ideone.com/Pkz2HC

Comment: Obrigado! Após a alteração, funcionou perfeitamente.